# Liquibase Error : Cannot load service: liquibase.hub.HubService: Provider liquibase.hub.core.StandardHubService could not be instantiated

Tags: sql-server, quarkus, liquibase, changeset, liquibase-sql

I am using liquibase in my quarkus application, where I want to perform a simple operation to execute a **.sql** file through the master changeLog.xml but upon running the same I am getting the below error:

> "Quarkus Main Thread", "message" : "Cannot load service: liquibase.hub.HubService: Provider liquibase.hub.core.StandardHubService could not be instantiated"

Though I can see the success message that my chnageLog.xml has executed with the correct **Changeset ID** in the console and I found one new record in **DATABASECHANGELOG** table with the same id and EXECTYPE is **EXECUTED** but still the insert query which is written in the .sql file is not executed.

Below are the dependencies in POM for liquibase:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-liquibase</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mssql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
quarkus.liquibase.migrate-at-start=true
```

changeLog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
    https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
    https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd">
        
    
<changeSet author="liquibase-test-5" id="sqlFile-example-5">
     <sqlFile dbms="sqlserver" splitStatements="true"
        path="liquibase-test.sql"
        relativeToChangelogFile="true"
        stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
    
</databaseChangeLog>
```

liquibase-test.sql:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (id,name) VALUES (2,'Salman');
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you please open an issue in the Quarkus Github repository and attach a sample application that exhibits the problem and that we can use to debug?

Comment: @geoand, Could you please paste the link here for reference where to open the issue and any other info if needed? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues